# The connected services component Microsoft WCF web service reference provider failed.(HRESULT: 0x80131500) the project format is incorrect

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, .net-core

I upgraded my project from dotNetCore 2.2 to 3.0 two weeks ago. Now I want to add a Webservice to it. I am using Visual Studio 2019

But I got this error when I clicked on **Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider**

None of the suggestions about Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider are the same error as mine

This is the error I got

> The connected services component Microsoft WCF web service reference
>   provider failed.(HRESULT: 0x80131500) the project format is incorrect

Can someone please suggest a fix for this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a fix / workaround for this? (Other than using svcutil)

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I removed  the package System.ServiceModel in the csproj.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: If you have already created a reference and remove reference, this solution will work.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thank you for saving the day!

Answer (score 4):

I recently upgraded my .Net 5 project to .Net 6 using Visual Studio 2022 current (v17.0.0) and found that removing the below from the .csproj file fixed the problem for me.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider in my VS2019 and found no error. This is my VS2019 related information:
[image]

You can show me the version information of your VS2019,Or you can reinstall VS2019 that the version information of VS2019 is consistent with that in the picture.

You can also generate proxy classes through svcutil.You can use this tool on the command-line interface of VS:
[image]

Executing the above command will generate the a proxy class and configuration file on disk D.Then add these two files to your project.

Here's a link about svcutil:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x

Comment: Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider is ok on other projects. Its only on this particular project that the problem is

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an old package referenced in the csproj. After removing it from there, the error disappeared.

Removed package:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022,
Issue is that if you are create new project with that It is working properly.
But some how It is not working with old or Migration time.

So I have suggest just Create new Project and Move Code Old to New Project.