# Unable to add WCF service as Connected Service in .NetStandard2.0 Class Library project

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-standard-2.0

I upgraded a C# Class Library Project from .Net Framework 4.5.2 to .NetStandard2.0. Post migration, I removed the existing Web References (which were present in .Net framework) and trying to add them as Connected Services. However, I'm getting an error when I choose "WCF Web Reference" in the "Add Service Reference" dialog. Below is the screenshot of the error:

[image: Add WCF service error]

I already referred to the below StackOverflow question and followed the solution. There are no item group in my .csproj that could be causing this issue.

[similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816313/the-connected-services-component-microsoft-wcf-web-service-reference-provider-fa)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: What is your version of VS? Try to reinstall it.

Comment: VS2019 Version: 16:11:23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scrutinizing the .csproj file, found that these references were still present and causing the issue. Removing the below lines from .csproj resolved the issue.

```
    <Reference Update="System.Core">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="System.Runtime.Serialization">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="System.Xml.Linq">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Thank You, I had the same problem and found that the reference to System.Core was the problem.